# typedef int* intptr OR typedef int *intptr;

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Instinctively I found where to put spaces in pointer declarations:

```
int system(const char *command);   // <-- right
int* foo() { return 0; }           // <-- wrong
int *X = 123;                      // <-- right
int* Y = 321;                      // <-- wrong
int *Z = (int*) X += (int*)Y       // <-- right
#define pchar char*                // <-- right
```

but this still puzzles me:

```
typedef int* intptr;
```

OR

```
typedef int *intptr;
```

Where the star belongs, left or right?

Comment: It's a matter of preference.

Comment: In my opinion, the latter is correct.  Keep in mind that '*' means 'contents of'.  You are declaring a variable whose contents are a char.

Comment: @user2580516 intptr isn't a variable, it's a type. It's an alias for the type `int*`. In languages with a better design, the type would be something like `^int`. And `*` does not mean "contents of" in a type, it means "pointer to [type]".

Comment: @JimBalter If `*` means 'pointer to', how come `a = *b` results in `a` containing the contents of `b`, rather than a pointer to b?

Comment: @user2580516 I said "in a type". If you don't understand the difference between a type declarator and an expression then you don't belong in this conversation. `int* x` means "x is a **pointer to** int". Oh, and `a = *b` doesn't get the contents of `b`, `a = b` does ... `*` is the *dereference* operator. These are C basics ... go learn them. I'm done here.

Comment: @JimBalter if `b` is a pointer, then `a = b` just gets you another pointer.  In c, a pointer or reference is designated by `&`, not `*`, speaking of c basics.

Comment: @user2580516 `a = b` sets the contents of `a` to the contents of `b`. You're misusing the word contents -- the contents of a pointer variable is the pointer value, not what's stored there. And I've programmed in C for 40 years and was on the C Standards committee, so I know the basics. Enough now, this conversation doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent.  The choice is a matter or personal preference.